# How to extend generated grpc contract class

Tags: c#, grpc-c#

I use grpc for service interaction. I have `MyNamespaceA` which is the output folder for grpc generated code. So I create the following `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespaceA";

message MyClass
{
    int32 myProp1 = 1;
}
```

Next, in my `.csproj`

```
<Protobuf Include="path_to_proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
```

So the following class is generated in `MyNamespaceA`:

```
namespace MyNamespaceA
{
    public sealed partial class MyClass: pb::IMessage<MyClass>
    ...
}
```

I want to add some more properties to this class. So I create a codefile (physically it is in another folder but I specify the correct namespace in the file itself) with the following contents:

```
namespace MyNamespaceA
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Aaand it does not work. When in my service I try to access `myClassInstance.MyProperty` I get an error

`The name 'MyProperty' does not exist in the current context`

The same thing is when I try to access `MyProp1` from my partial class - it simply does not see if it exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *namespace* is the generated class in? (Just because it's in a folder with that name doesn't mean that's the namespace.) Both parts of the partial class need to match in terms of namespace declaration. Within your partial class, can you write a method which refers to other aspects of the message? I'm guessing you'll get an error there too. (If you could provide a [mcve] it would be much easier to help you.)

Comment: Are you able to open the generated code, and is it *definitely* correctly generating a namespace of `MyNamespaceA`? And these are *definitely* in the same project? (At this point it might be worth putting a minimal example on GitHub so it's easy to experiment with...)

Comment: @JonSkeet the projects are _definitely_ not the same. My bad, didn't know that partial classes should be placed in the same project. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've added an answer that will hopefully help others facing partial class issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was revealed in comments to be that the two partial class declaration were in different projects. For two partial class declarations to "merge", they must:

- Be in the same project (because only a single actual class is compiled into a single assembly)
- Be declared in the same namespace
- Be declared with the same name

There are then requirements around matching modifiers etc, but the compiler will flag if those aren't met... whereas if any of the above three conditions isn't met, the compiler won't even consider that the two declarations are *trying* to contribute to the same class.